# Что скажете о коде по нахождению простых чисел?

Tags: c++

Надо было найти простые числа. Как вам такой вариант?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    //      Prosti numerics
    int n = 10,q = 0;
    cout << "2 3 5 7 ";

    while (q < 10)
    {
        n++;
        if (n%2 != 0) if (n%3!= 0) if (n%5!= 0) if (n%7!= 0) cout << n << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Поздравляю! Вы научились программировать бесконечные циклы!

Comment: а зачем такая вложенность if? и 1 никогда не было простым числом.

Comment: @KoVadim, оу, действительно)

Comment: Зачем Вы просите прощения у `numerics`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В программе есть много ошибок. Часть уже указали.

- 1 не простое число
- цикл бесконечный (как также заметил @kff)
- условие можно записать проще.
- находит не все простые числа (после исправления кода)

Исправим явные ошибки

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    //      prime numerics
    int n = 10;
    cout << "2 3 5 7 ";

    while (n < 1000)
    {
        n++;
        if (n%2 != 0 && n%3!= 0 && n%5!= 0 && n%7!= 0) cout << n << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Но даже теперь, программа найден "простое число" 121 или 143, или 169 (и много много других, которые не являются простыми).

Само условие "эксперты" могут записать даже так `(n%2 && n%3 && n%5 && n%7)`, но думаю, это уже перебор.

Comment: А почему перебор,  это не принято или читаемость сильно страдает? P.S. я вместо n%2 привык n & 1 писать.

Comment: Можно и &1 писать, но в данном случае лучше однообразие. Да и компилятор давно умеет это оптимизировать.

Comment: @KoVadim, у `&1` и `%2` несколько разная реакция на отрицательные числа. Поэтому предпочитаю `&1`.

Comment: А много отрицательных простых чисел Вы знаете?

Comment: @pavel, и совершенно напрасно. Код должен доносить свою суть, а не быть обфусцированным нечто.

Answer (score 2):

Ваш код не выдерживает никакой критики. Вот простейший код, вычисляющий простые числа. Алгоритм ужасно неэффективный, но работает.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const unsigned max = 100;
    std::vector<unsigned> simple;

    for (unsigned n = 2; n <= max; ++n) {
        bool isSimple = true;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < simple.size(); ++i) {
            if (n % simple[i] == 0) {
                isSimple = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isSimple) {
            simple.push_back(n);
            std::cout << n << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. Неэффективность, кстати, относительная. К памяти этот алгоритм относится почти максимально экономно, а вот скорость работы оставляет желать много лучшего. Тем не менее, простые числа до миллиона вычисляет менее чем за минуту.

Answer (score 2):

да здравствует классическая решётка Эратосфена !

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdio>

#define MAX 1000

using namespace std;

bool prime[MAX + 2];

int main()
{
    int p, d;
    prime[0] = prime[1] = 0;
    for (p = 3; p <= MAX; p += 2)
        prime[p] = true;

    for (p = 3; p*p <= MAX; p += 2)
    {
        if (prime[p])
            for (d = p*p; d <= MAX; d += p)
                prime[d] = 0;
    }

    printf("2\n");
    for (p = 3; p <= MAX; p += 2)
    {
        if (prime[p])
            printf("%d\n", p);  
    }

    return 0;
}
```